# Xcode not generating app with latest changes

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

My latest changes in Ionic app are not reflected on simulator or in ipa file which i am generating with xcode 10.

I tried many solution like removed build folder, remove ios folder from platform and add it again but none of works.

Any one has idea what might be problem is ?

Comment: Have you tried to emulate your app directly with `ionic cordova emulate ios`?

Comment: No, I will run that and will update you, Thanks for your reply @matthiasunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use these commands

```
cordova clean
```

and

```
npm run clean
```

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 10 you likely will need to force the use of the legacy build system.  This is described in [this blog post](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009511574-2018-09-21-Building-Locally-using-Xcode-10).

**Summary**: Create a `build.json` file in the root of your project with the following contents:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```