# Code changes are not reflected after running the app on ios device

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic4, xcode10.1

I'm working on a mobile app using ionic v4 and my problem is when I try to debug the app on my device I can't see the changes which I did in the file `'app.component.html'`(this problem is only for this file)
I'm using vscode for coding and xCode 10 to debug the app on my device

> ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.11.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v11.10.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.7.0
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: Only in app.component don't change? So, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54098386/10514656) don't help you?

Comment: it shows me a problem with the gradle (because I have the android platform also included to my project) i will fix the problem of the gradle and I will try this solution

Comment: After adding the gradle to the HOME variable I tried your solution but the first command `cordova clean` gave this error `> Configure project :CordovaLib
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android`